# In Java, my MouseMotionListener and MouseListener is detecting clicks, but not movement

Tags: java, swing, mouse

so I am creating a java game and and here is my mouse's clicks are being detected but the `mouseMoved` is not being run at all. There is a print statement in the method which never gets run. I am really stuck because since the clicks are being registered across the window, there shouldn't be anything wrong with the mouse motion.

Is the mouse dependent on anything else because I really have no idea what is causing this.

Thanks.

```
public class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    private static int mouseX = -1;
    private static int mouseY = -1;
    private static int mouseB = -1;

    public static int getX(){
        return mouseX;
    }

    public static int getY(){
        return mouseY;
    }

    public static int getB(){
        return mouseB;
    }



    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Moved");
        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseB = e.getButton();
        System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseB = -1;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Here is my game constructor which initiates everything.

```
public Game(){
        //cCursor();

        screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        mouse = new Mouse();
        keys = new Keyboard();
        //level = new RandomLevel(64, 64);
        level = Level.spawn;
        TileCoord pSpawn = new TileCoord(20,66);
        player = new Player(pSpawn.x(), pSpawn.y(), keys);
        player.init(level);

        addKeyListener(keys);
        addMouseListener(mouse);
    }
```

Comment: Don't rely on `static`, it is NOT a cross object communication mechanism

Comment: Ok, how do you recommend that I implement the mouse for use across my classes and objects, I haven't really used the mouse that often in my java games and applications so I don't really have much experience with the best way to do things.

Comment: Focus your efforts into a single view of possible, where the all the inputs can be directed; use a model which can updated and observed or queried

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice but now `mouseMoved` only happens when I am not holding down the mouse button. While I have my mouse button pressed, the variables do not update.

Comment: That's because it's become a `mouseDragged` event instead...

Comment: Alright should I set the x and y variables in the mouseDragged as well or is there a faster way to do so.

Comment: That all depends on what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to know where the mouse is when it's been dragged, then I would guess so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MouseMoitionListener` is a different listener to `MouseListener` and needs to be registered separately...

Start by adding a call to `addMouseMotionListener`

```
addMouseListener(mouse);
addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
```

Have a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details